# ASP.NET Core: Docker restore/build failed to include the 3rd party assembly from project

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core

Good day everyone,

I'm trying to containerize my ASP.NET Core Application. In my previous projects, this sample docker file works perfectly fine.

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:sdk AS build-env

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app/MyApp
RUN dotnet build

RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime
EXPOSE 80
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/MyApp/out .
ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet","MyApp.dll" ]
```

But the problem is, I have a project application that uses a 3rd party assembly or dll (Covered by red marker).

[image]

In my local project solution, it compiles and runs alright. But when I'm trying to build my project image, the C# files that use that assembly return an error, it says `The type or namespace name 'the_assembly' could not be found.` This happens when the docker step is in `RUN dotnet build`,`RUN dotnet restore` or `RUN dotnet publish...`

Any help please?

Comment: Does this reference is in a public nuget repository? If it does not, it is in a **private** repository? If yes, there is an option in `dotnet restore` to specify which package source the framework will consider.

Comment: Check your csproj file if it holds that dll reference as realitve location somewhere in your solution. Maybe you have it in some other place, so this file is not included in docker copy.

Comment: @RogersonNazário I've tried the `dotnet restore` please check above question. That dll is not in nuget. Just a package for supporting 3rd party device.

Comment: @Raik that package is included inside my csproject file

Comment: @AppleCiderYummy But is it pointing realitve location ? Maybe you have project in D:/projects/project1/something.csproj . But your libary is in D:/libaries/something. Then docker is unable to copy your dll.

Comment: @Raik I already tried putting the dll in the same project path. But still, I'm getting an error

Comment: @Raik Please put your comment to answer section. I'll mark it as the answer. Thank you for the tip, after days of trying to make solution, I moved the dll folder on the specific class library that uses that dll. Now it works on my CI docker build :) It just annoying since it works in a local compile and run time when the dll is one folder away from it's class library

Comment: Okay, nice to hear you made it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your csproj file if it holds that dll reference as realitve location somewhere in your solution. Maybe you have it in some other place, so this file is not included in docker copy.